# PHP is handling incorrectly my static call

Tags: php, class, methods, static, php-5.3

I'm havinh a problem on PHP 5.3. I need to call a method by using `__callStatic`, but if I use it in a instancied object, PHP call `__call` instead.

Above a real life example:

```
<?php

    class A {
        function __call($method, $args){
            // Note: $this is defined!
            echo "Ops! Don't works. {$this->c}";
        }

        static function __callStatic($method, $args){
            echo 'Fine!';
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        public $c = 'Real Ops!';

        function useCallStatic(){
            static::foo();
            // === A::foo();
            // === B::foo();
        }
    }

    $foo = new B();
    $foo->useCallStatic();

    // This works:
    // B::foo();

?>
```

**Prints**: Ops! Don't works. Real Ops!

Note that I call `useCallStatic` from a `new B()`. If I call directly works fine like `B::foo()`.

What I can do to it works fine?

Comment: What if you made `useCallStatic()` static?

Comment: At first glance, it seems like a bug. If you remove the `__call`, it works fine.

Comment: @Bolt It works, but the problem is that I really need to call *objective*, one time that I will use `$this` on `useCallStatic`, but not on `foo`.

Comment: @Kon yeah! If I remove works fine. I'm really thinking that it is a bug. But I not found on PHP Bugs.

Comment: & myself. It's not a bug, even though it sort of looks like one. One must remember that `::` in the context of a class method does not mean "call this static function" but only "call this function after resolving which class to use." The `__call` method happens to have precedence over the `__callStatic` method when either would be appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After thinking about it, it's not really a bug. But it's definitely unintuitive.

```
<?php
class A
{
  public function foo()
  {
    static::bar();
  }

  public function bar()
  {
    echo "bar()\n";
  }
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo();
```

This is valid, and calls bar(). It does not mean call bar statically. It means to look up the current class name and call function `bar` if it exists, whether or not it's a static function.

To clarify a bit more: do you think `parent::bar()` means to call a static function called `bar()`? No, it means call whatever function is named `bar()`.

Consider:

```
<?php
class A
{
  function __call($name, $args)
  {
    echo "__call()\n";
  }

  static function __callStatic($name, $ags)
  {
    echo "__callStatic()\n";
  }

  function regularMethod()
  {
    echo "regularMethod()\n";
  }

  static function staticMethod()
  {
    echo "staticMethod()\n";
  }

}

class B extends A
{
  function foo()
  {
    parent::nonExistant();   
    static::nonExistant();
    parent::regularMethod();
    parent::staticMethod(); 
  }
}

$b = new B();
$b->foo();
```

The `parent::nonExistant()` method invokes `A::__call()`, as does `static::nonExistant()`. Invoking `A::__callStatic()` for *either* call would be equally as valid! There is no way for PHP to know which one you want to be called. However, by design, PHP gives `__call` the priority when invoked from this sort of context.

`parent::regularMethod()` invokes the non static function `regularMethod()`. (Again, the `::` operator does not mean "call this static function.") Likewise `parent::staticMethod()` invokes `A::staticMethod()` as one might expect.

To solve your problem:

You could manually call `self::__callStatic('foo')` in the inherited class.

Or within the `__call` method of class A filter against a known list and call `self::__callStatic`.

```
function __call($f, $a)
{
  if ($f == 'foo')
    return self::__callStatic($f, $a); 
  else
  {
  }
}
```

It's ugly, but at least people who extend the class won't need to do anything special.

Comment: it is a good answer, but the problem is that the final method can be called by two modes: with context or static. Have a small difference between this methods, but it can't be ignored. It's just the problem.

Comment: It's a bad design on your end if a method with the same name can be called in two different ways (static or not). There is no way that I am aware of that you can force a static call while within a method function in the way you desire.

Comment: Yeah. I need rethink my design. Maybe it is possible yet. Thanks for everybody.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to the standard notation of calling parent methods, regardless of state. You could check if the `$this` keyword is set in the `__call` method and if not, make a call to `__callStatic` ?

EDIT: This isn't a bug per se, the static call is being made from an object context. Take a look at [this bug thread on php](http://bugs.php.net/51176).

Comment: @Jaitsu I can't. `__call` is important too, I need use it on some moments. Is possible to check if is a static call?

Comment: If you check that `$this` is set (i.e. `isset($this)`) then you can determine whether it's a static call or not (`$this` won't be set in a static call)

Comment: @Jaitsu it is, but `$this` is defined too :( I have tried this before.

Comment: What about... `$is_static = !(isset($this) && get_class($this) == __CLASS__)`. Scrap that, I'm forgetting this is in a non-static method... hmm

Comment: @Jaitsu don't works. `static::foo` and `$this->foo` returns same (`true`).

Comment: @David Rodrigues, I updated my answer. Not sure that there is a way around this without rethinking your design

Comment: @Jaitsu Yeah! I noted this. But don't make sense, because if I call `static::` I won't take context. If I want context, I need use `$this->` not?

Comment: @David, see my answer... Jaitsu is right. It's not a bug, it's how it's supposed to work. `static::` or `self::` (etc) does not mean to call a static method. It just affects how it looks up the class. (If you are in a static context, it will call a static method... but only because calling an instance method makes no sense in that case.)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you're using PHP 5.3.0 or newer, as that's when __callStatic was implemented.  It all seems to work as expected, see this example:

```
<?php
class A {
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        echo 'A::__call, ' .
           var_export(array($method, $args), true), PHP_EOL;
    }

    /** As of PHP 5.3.0 */
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
        echo 'A::__callStatic, ' .
           var_export(array($method, $args), true), PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->foo('abc');
A::bar('123');

class B extends A {
    function invokeStatic($args) {
        echo 'B::invokeStatic', PHP_EOL;
        self::someStatic($args);
    }
}

$b = new B;
$b->invokeStatic('456');
?>
```

The output should be (or at least, it is for me):

```
A::__call, array (
  0 => 'foo',
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'abc',
  ),
)
A::__callStatic, array (
  0 => 'bar',
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '123',
  ),
)
B::invokeStatic
A::__callStatic, array (
  0 => 'someStatic',
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '456',
  ),
)
```

When I run your example above, I just get "Fine!" as the only output, which is exactly what I would have expected.

Exactly what version of PHP are you running?  You can check with this:

```
$ php -r 'echo phpversion(), PHP_EOL;'
5.3.3-7+squeeze1
```

Comment: Upgrade to 5.3.4 and you won't get that behavior. None of these while called inside a class method mean "call a static function": `parent::foo()`, `self::foo()`, `static::foo()`. They simply mean call function `foo()` after resolving the object on the left of the `::` operator. If both `__call` and `__callStatic` are defined and you are calling from within a non-static context, the former takes precedence. Neither way is "correct" or a "bug" because it's an ambiguous call. At least by giving `__call` priority, you can forward the call to `__callStatic` as my answer suggests.

Comment: Interesting - I just tested on PHP 5.3.6, and indeed static resolution has changed (and IMHO, feels broken) as both of you have pointed out.  The whole *point* of `__callStatic()` was to have PHP handle the routing of method invocations vs. static function calls, rather than overloading `__call()` ...

Comment: I would go so far as to say this IS a bug, because even `forward_static_call()` isn't invoking `__callStatic()` in the parent class, which is the whole point of the newly introduced function.

Perhaps this will get fixed in PHP 5.3.7?  Still, good to know that this was changed and between which release versions.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance of static methods is a bit weird in PHP. I suspect you need to redefine `__callStatic` in `B`

Comment: I can't redefine, it is a Framework that I'm developing. Is a bit annoying to ask the user to redefine a method

Comment: But if you do redefine, does it work as expected? I guess another solution would be to use reflection and figure out which functions are static? Is it really absolutely necessary to use `__call` at all? I'm not a big fan because of crazy issues like these and implied magic. Maybe just wait till we get _traits_?

Comment: if I redefine, it *don't* works too. :/ The second suggestion is good (*maybe* I use that). But if the static method don't exists on this case, I can't handle `__callStatic` to show an error, for instance. You get?

Answer (score 0):

**Good news**

I make a BIG work arround, but it works pretty fine. This is the code:

```
class NoContext {
    public static function call($callback, $args = null){
        return call_user_func_array($callback, $args ?: array());
    }
}
```

You need to call `NoContext::call` (statically) like you call `call_user_func` or similar. It will to remove the `$this` context. I still thinks that it is a PHP bug, but...

To solve my problem, I do:

```
class B extends A {
    function useCallStatic(){
        NoContext::call('A::foo');
    }
}
```

And it will prints: `Fine!`.

Thanks everybody that help me. I really learn too much with your replies and I wait that my tips be userful sometime to you.