# Calling static function from instance

Tags: php, methods, static, instance

I'm trying to call a static magic function (`__callStatic`) from a member of its child class. Problem being, it goes to the non-static `__call` instead.

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", true);

class a
{
    function __call($method, $params)
    {
        echo "instance";
    }

    static function __callStatic($method, $params)
    {
        echo "static";
    }
}

class b extends a
{
    function foo()
    {
        echo static::bar();
        // === echo self::bar();
        // === echo a::bar();
        // === echo b::bar();
    }
}

$b = new b();
echo phpversion()."<br />";
$b->foo();

?>
```

Output:

```
5.3.6
instance
```

How can I make it display "static"?

Comment: Hmm, on my php 5.3.3 I see "static" with your code.

Comment: Strange. On 5.3.6 (just tested as edit shows), I see "instance".

Comment: Seems like it is impossible, I found this discussion: http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/607508/919970.

Comment: Here: `Interestingly, PHP 5.3.3 gives __callStatic priority, but that behavior was reverted back in PHP 5.3.4.`

Comment: Very strange. My 5.3.6 says instance as well. Just had a look with all ZCE's I could grab. Nobody understands. I think it has to do with this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#97599 - This guy is able to save a variable in a static context, which should be impossible in my book. Maybe PHP artificially creates an instance for this and messes up the context. I'm confused :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP is handling incorrectly my static call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181603/php-is-handling-incorrectly-my-static-call)

Comment: Yeah, and seems like there is no way to explicitly call magic static method in php 5.3.4+.

Comment: see also https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51176

Comment: Wow, even though I "understand" why it's done like that, it's really horrible that there is no way in PHP to call this without hacks. It's a common procedure. And yes, it's a duplicate, but I personnally wouldn't accept the answer. I think the whole `parent::` and `self::` are syntaxically misleading, and `static::` is a misnomer. It could be `$base->`, `$this->` instead. Anywho, on to finding a hack now...

Comment: Lazlo Bonin, keep in mind you're dealing with object inheritance here. Even you think you have two classes, this is actually one. And that one class is not called statically if you do this: `$b->foo();`. That's not a static function call. The hack would be to do this instead: `$b::foo();`. Try it for yourself.

Comment: @hakre: Or `b::foo();` for that matter.

Comment: @Lazlo: Personally, I would tackle this problem by adding a condition inside the `__call()` magic method, and returning `call_user_func_array(array(__CLASS__, '__callStatic'), func_get_args());` if the method is inaccessible in a non-static context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you remove the magic method '__call', your code will return 'static'.

According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php "__callStatic() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context".

What I think is happening in your code is that,

1. You are calling static method from a non-static context.
2. The method call is in non-static context, so PHP searches for the magic method '__call'.
3. PHP triggers the magic method '_*call' if it's exists. Or, if it's not exists it will call '*_callStatic'.

**Here is a possible solution:**

```
class a
{
    static function __callStatic($method, $params)
    {
        $methodList =  array('staticMethod1', 'staticMethod2');

        // check if the method name should be called statically
        if (!in_array($method, $methodList)) {
            return false;
        }

        echo "static";

        return true;
    }

    function __call($method, $params)
    {
         $status = self::__callStatic($method, $params);
         if ($status) {
             return;
         }
         echo "instance";
    }

}

class b extends a
{
    function foo()
    {
        echo static::staticMethod1();
    }

    function foo2()
    {
        echo static::bar();
    }
}

$b = new b();
echo phpversion()."<br />";
$b->foo();
$b->foo2();
```

Comment: +1 for *"If you remove the magic method '__call', your code will return 'static'."* and the nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP there are the [reserved words `self` and `parent` for accessing static methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) from within a class and/or instantiated object. `parent` refers to inherited methods from the parent class.

```
class b extends a
{
    function foo()
    {
        echo parent::bar();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Uhm, that doesn't do the trick… (using PHP 5.3.5)

```
$b = new b();
$b->foo();  // displays: instance
a::bar();   // displays: static
```

2nd EDIT: Ha, it works only, if you omit the `__call()`-method in class `a`.

```
class a
{
    static function __callStatic($method, $params)
    {
        echo "static";
    }

//  function __call($method, $params)
//    {
//        echo "instance";
//    }
}

class b extends a
{
    function foo()
    {
        echo parent::bar();
    }
}

$b = new b();
$b->foo();  // displays: static
a::bar();   // displays: static
```

Comment: Replaced with `echo self::bar();`, still displaying "instance".

Comment: Well, yeah, but I *have* a `__call` method in my design that I need.