# accessing static (parent) class within instance of the same (sub) class

Tags: php, inheritance, static, polymorphism, instance

Hi fellow programmers!

I couldn't find an answer to this problem i'm having. I'm trying to statically access a magic method implemented by a parent class while inside a subclass's instance. Now, this may sound a bit weird, but i'll try to demonstrate below:

```
<?php

class Query {

    public function __call( $name, $arguments ){
        // this is also a point where the "where" function 
        // can end up if called on an instance instead of 
        // statically.. 
    }

    static public function __callStatic($name, $arguments){
        // this is where I had expected the "Node::where" to end up 
        $class = get_called_class();
        // here is where id like to create the new Node instance
        $obj = new $class();
        return call_user_func_array(array($obj, '_' . $name), $arguments);
    }
}

// and a different class extending the previous one

class Node extends Query {
    private $node_id = null;

    public function getChildren(){
        // commented out for it might lead to confusion
        // return Node::where("parent_node_id", "=", $this->node_id)->all();
        return Node::where("parent_node_id", "=", $this->node_id);
    }
}

// this is the parent Node object
$node = Node::find(1);

// and here I would like to get all the nodes where the parent
// node id equals the $node id 
$children = $node->getChildren();
```

Now, for some reason, when i`m in the $node instance, when I access Node::where(), this "Node::where()" resolves to the magic __call() instead of the __callStatic(). Is this expected behaviour and how can I access the same class within itself statically?

I've tried using self::where() and static::where() but both resolve to $this or the instance i'm currently in..

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `all()` that ends up in `__call()`, instead of `where()`?

Comment: Actually, the all() would probably render the same problem as both where(), all() and get() should follow the same paradigm. In this case, the all() is a bit unneccesary, both good for pointing that out :D

Comment: No, `where()`, `all()`, and `get()` do not follow the same paradigm. `all()` is an instance method. I don't see `get()` defined or used in your code, but it probably is an instance method as well. Note that `__callStatic` instantiates a class, then calls `call_user_func_array` using that class. Is this app using Laravel/Eloquent by chance?

Comment: It is loosely based on the same paradigm Laravel implements, however I'm currently trying to implement a recursive inverse nested set (Forest/Tree) which requires a different approach ( and I like to understand how things work )

But coming back, the `where()`, `get()`, and `all()` in my example do follow the same approach, as all these methods are allowed to be called on an instance as well as statically.

Comment: I think this gives you an answer and a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750038/calling-static-function-from-instance

Comment: I think it explains it, but it does not encompass my situation entirely, as I would like the static __callStatic() to precede the __call() or otherwise, have a way to circumvent the "call from within the instance" if possible.