# Eloquent methods use child class instead of parent when called from within child

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I think I might have found a quirk of the code that allows Laravel Eloquent model methods to be called statically, but could do with some help.

I have a Model called `FormSubmission` which extends `Eloquent\Model`.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class FormSubmission extends Model 
{

    /**
     * Should always return a Collection of FormSubmissions
     *
     * @param $formSubmissionIds
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    protected function getFormSubmissions(array $formSubmissionIds) : Collection
    {
        return FormSubmission::whereIn('id', $formSubmissionIds)->get();
    }

}
```

I needed a place to put some logic that is unique to only 1 type of FormSubmission. As it is not relevant to all forms I did not want to pollute the `FormSubmission` model so I have made `EmployeeFormSubmission` which extends `FormSubmission`.

```
namespace App;

class EmployeeFormSubmission extends FormSubmission 
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function getTest()
    {
        $employeeFormSubmission = new EmployeeFormSubmission();

        // The resulting Collection will contain instances 
        // of EmployeeFormSubmission (not FormSubmission).
        return $employeeFormSubmission->getFormSubmissions([86]);
    }

}
```

Eloquent **Model** -> extended by **FormSubmission** -> extended by **EmployeeFormSubmission**

**The problem...**

The strange behaviour which I am having trouble understanding is that if I call the `whereIn()` method on `FormSubmission` from within `EmployeeFormSubmission` like in the getTest() example above, the resulting Collection will contain instances of `EmployeeFormSubmission`, even though I am explicitly calling the `whereIn()` method on `FormSubmission` model.

The behaviour is the same if I use `parent::whereIn()`

However, if I change `FormSubmission::getFormSubmissions()` method to be a public static, it works as expected and returns a Collection of instances of `FormSubmission`.

It's as if Laravel/PHP is substituting "FormSubmission::" for "self::" when inside a non-static method on `FormSubmission`.

When non-static, it's holding on to the context in which the code is executed and initialising the items within as instances of that class. But when static, it honours the model name referenced in the line of code.

Please help I am a bit stumped.

Comment: Can you add an example method to `EmployeeFormSubmission` that shows this behavior?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir have expanded the example in the question to include an actual working example

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that calls to undefined static methods like `FormSubmission::whereIn()` don't get handled by `__callStatic()`, but by `__call()` ([PHP is handling incorrectly my static call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6181603/4848587)).

This works:

```
return FormSubmission::query()->whereIn('id', $formSubmissionIds)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and link to related question. I believe I have some learning to do to improve my understanding of static::